# swift 3. Specify selector for action and provide additional parameters to it

Tags: ios, swift, callback

I wonder if there is a way like in C++ to bind some values to function arguments and pass result with unresolved arguments.

Example(pseudo code):
void func(int start, int end, int step){...}
functor = getFunctionObject(func)
functor.bind("step", 10) -> result is fun(start, end) with step = 10,
so we can pass it to interface that expects this kind of function signature

why I need this:
I am working with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, it expects `#selector` for action, as I have multiple views from which this action might be triggered I want to know from what view I got notification.

What I am doing:

```
@IBOutlet weak var oneOfMyBtn: UIButton! {
    didSet {
      let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer( target: self, action: #selector(MyClass.onLongPress))
      oneOfMyBtn.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }
  }

func onLongPress(recg : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recg.state {
    case .began:
      print("LongPress detected")
    default:
      break
    }
  }
```

What I want is:

```
func onLongPress(recg : UILongPressGestureRecognizer, sender : UIButton) {
    switch recg.state {
    case .began:
      print("LongPress detected")
    default:
      break
    }

  }
```

as I need information which button triggered the action

How to do this?

Comment: The gesture recognizer has a `view` property you can use to get the view it was attached to (your button)

Comment: @dan yes, thank you very much, that is what I need, I shall accept your answer